# I would want to write regEx for character to accept from a-zA-z0-9 (from 1-to any) with mandatory one special character from . OR _

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I tried this:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])(?=[.|_]).$
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: please an example

Comment: what do you want in from regEx

Comment: need more explanation.
One special character is mandatory and what is character limit?

Comment: what string do you wan't to parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following regular expression, if you want **only one** special character:

```
/^[a-z\d]+[._][a-z\d]*|[a-z\d]*[._][a-z\d]+$/i
```

If, instead, you want **at least one** special character you can use the following:

```
/^(?:[a-z\d]+[._]+[a-z\d]*|[a-z\d]*[._]+[a-z\d]+)+$/i
```

Comment: But I added this ^[a-zA-z\d]*[._][a-zA-z\d]*$ to make it work properly with Uppercase also.

Comment: It will work for uppercase letters because of the `i` flag in the end :)

Comment: Click on the flag to the right of the textbox and select `insensitive`. In `Regex101` you don't insert the flags inside the main regular expression; in `JavaScript`, however, you should use it as I wrote it.

Comment: According to question one none-special character is mandatory which is still being ignored.

Comment: You are right @RehanHaider. Thanks for the heads-up. I edited my question to cover both cases. I also fixed the _`none-special character`_ issue you mentioned.

Comment: I think it is also a good alternative
`/^(?=.*[._])(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d])[._a-zA-Z\d]+$/`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one `^[a-zA-Z0-9[.][_][-]]+` and any special character is between two parenthesis

Comment: This is no valid regex?!